# Rails - active_link_to wrap tab not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the active_link_to gem on my navigation and whilst the documentation says you can use the wrap tag functionality, it's not working correctly for me.

As per the docs I created the link:

```
= active_link_to t('common.links.visual'), subject_visit_design_maintain_subject_visits_study_site_subject_subject_visits_path(@study, @site, @subject), wrap_tag: :li, wrap_class: 'main-nav-link'
```

But rather than wrapping the anchor tag in a list item tag, it's adding it as an attribute:

```
<a wrap_tag="li" wrap_class="main-nav-link" href="/maintain_subject_visits/studies/1/sites/19/subjects/63/subject_visits/subject_visit_design">
  Visual
</a>
```

Elsewhere I've used exactly the same method and it has produced the desired effect:

```
= active_link_to t('headers.reference_data'), application_references_path, wrap_tag: :li, wrap_class: 'main-nav-link'
```

Produces:

```
<li class="main-nav-link active">
  <a aria-current="page" href="/manage_application_references/application_references">
    Reference Data
  </a>
</li>
```

The only difference I can see between the two cases is that in the first it shares the menu with a regular `link_to` whereas in the latter it is a menu of only `active_link_to` methods.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The same thing is working fine on my machine `<li class="main-nav-link"><a href="/maintain_subject_visits/studies/1/sites/19/subjects/63/subject_visits/subject_visit_design">Visual</a></li>` try clearing cache and restart your server.

Comment: Strange. Can you think of something that would modify the behaviour of the method?